# VS 2017 is unable to analyze cordova plugin.xml from local or clone it from git

Tags: xml, git, cordova, plugins

I'm facing a little issue trying to implement a custom cordova plugin in my project. I'm new to cordova and I'm trying to add this [plugin](https://github.com/Uepaa-AG/p2pkit-cordova) but i didn't manage to add it on my solution.

If I try to add it locally VS return that it wasn't able to parse plugin.xml
If i try to add it via git general error occurs and his ID cannot be found

Does anybody happen to know a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've found the problem. For anyone facing the same problem it was made by the developer of the plugin because the plugin.xml wasn't well formatted. I've deleted the first rows of comments to let the `<?xml...>` be on top of the file